# Como unir dois data.frames de tamanhos diferentes por colunas no R?

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponhamos que tenho dois data.frames diferentes:

```
print(DADOS_1)

linha coluna1 coluna2
1     1       3
2     3       4
3     1       1
4     2       2

print(DADOS_2)

linha coluna3 coluna4
1     3       1
2     2       2
3     5       0
4     2       4
5     1       3
6     3       1
```

Eu preciso unir `DADOS_1` e `DADOS_2` por colunas, ou seja, que se unem lateralmente. O resultado deveria ser esse:

```
print(DADOS_1+2)

    linha coluna1 coluna2 coluna3 coluna 4
    1     1       3       3       1
    2     3       4       2       2
    3     1       1       5       0
    4     2       2       2       4
    5     NA      NA      1       3
    6     NA      NA      3       1
```

Tentei usar a função `bind_cols` mas ela me voltou com o seguinte erro:

```
Error: Argument 2 must be length 36550, not 138383
```

Que no caso está dizendo que não é possível unir meus dois data.frames por que ambos possuem tamanhos distintos.

O que devo fazer para unir meus dois data.frames de tamanhos diferentes por colunas no R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que os data frames já possuem uma coluna que sirva de identificação, dá pra usar o `dplyr::full_join` diretamente. Aproveitando a simulação apresentada [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/391728/49033), temos

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(linha = 1:10,  
  x = replicate(n = 8, expr = runif(10, 20, 100))
)

b <- data.frame(linha = 1:5,
  y = replicate(n = 4, expr = runif(5, 20, 100))
)

full_join(a, b, by = "linha")
```

Ou seja, basta indicar à função `dplyr::full_join` quais são os data frames a serem unidos e qual o nome da coluna que servirá de referência para esta união.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 4):

Suponha `a` (com 10 linhas) e `b` (com 5 linhas):

```
a <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(n = 8, expr = runif(10, 20, 100))
)


b <- data.frame(
  y = replicate(n = 4, expr = runif(5, 20, 100))
)
```

Agrora, crio uma lista:

```
library(tidyverse)

lista <- lst(a, b)
```

Trabalhar com listas permite que você faça *joins* com diversos bancos de dados, não apenas dois. Esta é a vantagem.

Com `tidyverse` você faz assim:

```
lista %>% 
  map(~ mutate(., rownames = row.names(.))) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = 'rownames')
```

- Note que precisei criar uma coluna (`rownames`) para fazer a comparação.

```
        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4      x.5      x.6      x.7      x.8 rownames
1  74.69882 35.89753 28.04641 90.21342 81.84718 48.05258 77.96111 57.18316        1
2  77.68592 95.76047 80.74215 60.79755 72.05111 99.42336 42.95387 97.24211        2
3  56.54784 42.12707 85.28353 93.75327 94.64186 57.47894 77.20191 62.89326        3
4  56.06928 44.25626 73.59108 36.27553 80.06120 40.40878 39.21776 96.30845        4
5  82.46494 59.77877 47.20289 52.71778 61.25111 87.92412 39.39340 70.68103        5
6  57.25800 60.69670 21.26649 85.86384 92.79378 74.92121 64.67908 60.38243        6
7  76.81113 89.46213 38.02942 93.48745 44.17187 38.44297 53.09666 85.19333        7
8  34.82535 80.53654 87.08810 21.20205 74.30482 49.67933 51.85050 59.47621        8
9  40.15681 71.67351 20.90501 80.65097 77.12172 27.66269 25.24923 30.93586        9
10 21.09820 66.00663 23.45102 82.09685 26.14959 20.94048 45.73111 53.22275       10
        y.1      y.2      y.3      y.4
1  57.51489 91.06000 50.09318 29.64023
2  85.18483 63.15968 38.07206 64.34042
3  58.85344 21.06321 36.06338 87.25948
4  20.23187 32.84291 83.87627 23.88338
5  43.17968 69.30414 28.58430 39.36796
6        NA       NA       NA       NA
7        NA       NA       NA       NA
8        NA       NA       NA       NA
9        NA       NA       NA       NA
10       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta vou testar.

Answer (score 3):

Só com R base, a função `merge` com o argumento `all = TRUE` faz o que a pergunta pede.

```
set.seed(1234)

a <- data.frame(linha = 1:4,  
                x = replicate(n = 2, expr = sample(0:5, 4, TRUE))
)

b <- data.frame(linha = 1:6,
                y = replicate(n = 2, expr = sample(0:5, 6, TRUE))
)

merge(a, b, all = TRUE)
#  linha x.1 x.2 y.1 y.2
#1     1   3   3   3   3
#2     2   1   0   1   5
#3     3   5   4   5   5
#4     4   4   5   1   5
#5     5  NA  NA   5   3
#6     6  NA  NA   5   3
```